# Interpreting the coordinates in a shapefile

Tags: geographics, coordinate-transformation, projection

I am trying to interpret the coordinates in the shapefile downloadable from [here](https://data.statistik.gv.at/web/meta.jsp?dataset=OGDEXT_GEM_MP_1) (Dataset 1).

We can extract coordinates like so:

```
coord = Import["STATISTIK_AUSTRIA_GEM_MP_20230101.shp", "Data"] // First // 
 Query["Geometry"]
```

How can I transform to something that can be plotted *accurately* with `GeoGraphics`?

This is what I have so far:

```
GeoGraphics[
 {Red, PointSize[Medium], 
  coord /. 
   Point[pt_] :> 
    Point@GeoPosition@GeoGridPosition[
      pt, 
      {"LambertConicConformal", 
         {"ReferenceModel" -> "Bessel1841", 
          "GridOrigin" -> {400000, 400000}, 
          "Centering" -> {47.5, 13.333333333333334`}, 
          "CentralScaleFactor" -> 1}}]},
 GeoRange -> Entity["Country", "Austria"]
]
```

This is not entirely accurate. There are visible deviations around the borders.

[image]

I filled out the projection parameters based on the following, and guidance from similar questions on this site, but there are several pieces of data in the coordinate system information that I couldn't figure out how to use:

```
In[]:= Import["STATISTIK_AUSTRIA_GEM_MP_20230101.shp", "CoordinateSystemInformation"]

Out[]= "PROJCS" -> {"MGI / Austria Lambert", 
  "GEOGCS" -> {"MGI", 
    "DATUM" -> {"Militar-Geographische Institut", 
      "SPHEROID" -> {"Bessel 1841", 6.3774*10^6, 299.153, 
        "AUTHORITY" -> {"EPSG", 7004}}, 
      "TOWGS84" -> {601.705, 84.263, 485.227, 
        4.7354, -1.3145, -5.393, -2.3887}, 
      "AUTHORITY" -> {"EPSG", 6312}}, 
    "PRIMEM" -> {"Greenwich", 0., "AUTHORITY" -> {"EPSG", 8901}}, 
    "UNIT" -> {"degree", 0.0174533}, 
    "AXIS" -> {"Geodetic longitude", "EAST"}, 
    "AXIS" -> {"Geodetic latitude", "NORTH"}, 
    "AUTHORITY" -> {"EPSG", 4312}}, 
  "PROJECTION" -> {"Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP", 
    "AUTHORITY" -> {"EPSG", 9802}}, 
  "PARAMETER" -> {"central_meridian", 13.3333}, 
  "PARAMETER" -> {"latitude_of_origin", 47.5}, 
  "PARAMETER" -> {"standard_parallel_1", 49.}, 
  "PARAMETER" -> {"false_easting", 400000.}, 
  "PARAMETER" -> {"false_northing", 400000.}, 
  "PARAMETER" -> {"scale_factor", 1.}, 
  "PARAMETER" -> {"standard_parallel_2", 46.}, "UNIT" -> {"m", 1.}, 
  "AXIS" -> {"Easting", "EAST"}, "AXIS" -> {"Northing", "NORTH"}, 
  "AUTHORITY" -> {"EPSG", 31287}}
```

In particular, it is unclear to me how to make use of the `DATUM` field.

#### References

- [GeoPosition coordinates from Shape file (.SHP) with unknown Datum](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124121/12)
- [How to convert from and to UTM coordinates in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17448/12)
- [What is the Wolfram Language Native Function to tranform lat /lon from WGS84 to x/y EPSG 3857?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/263481/12)

Comment: See [`Bessel 1841`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_ellipsoid)